# Can I deactivate the user who is also the owner of an Einstein Dashboard/ Dataflow. On deactivation, the dashboard was not reflecting updated data

Tags: einstein-analytics, dashboard, einstein

Can I deactivate the User who is also the owner of an Einstein Dashboard/ Dataflow.
These dashboards are used by executives and on deactivation, the dashboard was not reflecting updated data. However, I didn't encountered any official error but the data refresh stopped.

Answer (score 0):

As per best practice, you should keep dashboards in Apps and give access to app (Share App with Certain set of Users/Roles/profiles),

Potential reason why data refresh stopped is because you might have placed dashboard in Private folder of user whom you want to deactivate.

** Private dashboards which are placed in private folder might not be accessible and might now refresh data.